# What book did Philip K. Dick dedicate to Heinlein?

Tags: story-identification, books, robert-a-heinlein, philip-k-dick

There's a famous quote from Philip K Dick about Heinlein mentioned on the [Philip K. Dick Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick#Career) and on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1555/35):

> One time when I owed the IRS a lot of money and couldn't raise it,
>   Heinlein loaned the money to me. I think a great deal of him and his
>   wife; **I dedicated a book to them in appreciation.**

What book did Dick dedicate to the Heinleins?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's [*We Can Build You*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Can_Build_You). Well, I think it is because my edition has on page 5:

> To Robert and Ginny Heinlein, whose kindness to us meant more than ordinary words can answer.

However [the edition on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Can-Build-You-Philip-Dick/dp/0006482791/ref=sr_1_1) does not have this page. My edition is the 1994 one from Vintage Books/Random House while the one on Amazon is a 2012 edition from Mariner Books/Houghton Mifflin Harcourt.

The 1972 publication date fits because Dick's comments were made in 1980 in the introduction to The Golden Man in 1980.

Having said all this, the normally infallible Google returns no obviously relevant hits on the subject. Maybe any forum members who own the book could check their editions.

Comment: The 1972 date also fits, as when I was trying to find this last night, his IRS hassles were from 1967-1969. +1.

Comment: Search for "Heinlein" in [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=xTlNPgg9uvEC&q=heinlein#v=snippet&q=heinlein&f=false).