# Terry Pratchett book which had a preamble about a school principal who suspended a child

Tags: story-identification, books, terry-pratchett

I am seeking a Terry Pratchett book with a preamble discussing a student who was suspended from school for bringing one of Terry Pratchett's books to the classroom; when the child came again with the book (allowed by Mom), the school had the child removed from her home as the book was "anti-school" or "anti-principal."

Comment: Are you certain this is a Pratchett book?  (A) I've never read this in any of his books (and I just did a search across the e-texts of most of them); (B) the only matching result I get back in a variety of google searches is this question.

Comment: Pratchett or not, what was science-fiction/fantasy about this very story? I know Pratchett wrote a lot of SFF (maybe even only SFF?) but so far it doesn't look very on-topic.

Comment: I don't recall this in any Terry Pratchett book. Not only that, but teachers usually fall over themselves to praise Pratchett for inspiring kids to read

Comment: Eyeh, we do allow non-SFF queries about SFF authors and their books. It does seem a bit odd that a kid would be taken from their parents over this sort of thing...

Comment: @Valorum When Terry Pratchett started writing, some schools (especially strict religious ones) were less tolerant of fantasy. A coworker who happened to be on a school board told me the story of some people who objected (in a public board meeting) to the teaching of science because it was 'sorcery'. You never know how bonkers some people can get. You can't call this off-topic until the essay is identified. Anyway, if it's a preface to an actual Pratchett fantasy novel, it could be considered on-topic for 'history-of' or 'fandom' reasons.

Comment: Could this have been a news story or (maybe SFF) magazine article?

Comment: @Spencer - Agreed. That said, I'm happy to let it stew in the closed pile unless someone can identify the work

Comment: The question [What book did Philip K. Dick dedicate to Heinlein?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/what-book-did-philip-k-dick-dedicate-to-heinlein) is also about the introduction to a book and that is not only still open but highly upvoted. I don't see why this question should be closed when it's basically similar.

Comment: The referenced incident seems likely to be apocryphal -- it would at the least require the local child protection authorities to agree with the school administration that the book was harmful *to the child*.  Can't say this would never happen in certain parts of the USA, but Pratchett was British and his books were, in general, first published in England.

Comment: Unless there's evidence that this was actually a Terry Pratchett story AND that it was one of Terry Pratchett's science fiction or fantasy works, I see no reason why this should remain open.

Comment: @Valorum: "let it stew in the closed pile unless someone can identify the work" - uh, that's not how StackExchange works. For starters, closed questions *can't be answered*.

Comment: @Martha - No, but if someone thinks they know the answer, they can post a meta, a comment, post a reopen vote, etc. There's lots of ways to get an *apparently off-topic question that turns out to be on-topic* back open

Comment: The closest I can think is a mention by Piers Anthony that his books were once used in a child custody case to prove unfitness.